# Cannot set rustflags target-cpu=native in Cargo.toml (SIMD-JSON)

Tags: rust, simd, rust-cargo

I'm trying to compile the Rust simd-json package. It complains that the box is not SIMD-compatible:

```
    |
221 | fn please_compile_with_a_simd_compatible_cpu_setting_read_the_simdjsonrs_readme() -> ! {}
    |    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------      ^ expected `!`, found `()`
    |    |
    |    implicitly returns `()` as its body has no tail or `return` expression
```

However, the box is `x86` as required:

```
$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-68-220 5.15.0-1011-aws #14-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 1 20:54:22 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And `Cargo.toml` contains the required compiler flags:

```ini
[build]
rustflags = ["-C", "target-cpu=native"]

[target.wasm32-unknown-unknown]
rustflags = ["-C", "target-feature=+simd128"]

[target.wasm32-wasi]
rustflags = ["-C", "target-feature=+simd128"]
```

Why is simd-json unhappy?

Full `/proc/cpuinfo` output below.

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 85
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8259CL CPU @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x500320a
cpu MHz     : 2500.006
cache size  : 36608 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves ida arat pku ospke
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 5000.01
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 85
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8259CL CPU @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x500320a
cpu MHz     : 2500.006
cache size  : 36608 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves ida arat pku ospke
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 5000.01
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 85
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8259CL CPU @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x500320a
cpu MHz     : 2500.006
cache size  : 36608 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves ida arat pku ospke
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 5000.01
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 85
model name  : Intel(R) Xeon(R) Platinum 8259CL CPU @ 2.50GHz
stepping    : 7
microcode   : 0x500320a
cpu MHz     : 2500.006
cache size  : 36608 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq ssse3 fma cx16 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch invpcid_single pti fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid mpx avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves ida arat pku ospke
bugs        : cpu_meltdown spectre_v1 spectre_v2 spec_store_bypass l1tf mds swapgs itlb_multihit
bogomips    : 5000.01
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: Perhaps you have an older CPU that doesn't support AVX2 or SSE4.2? Check if either is listed in the flags for your CPU in `/proc/cpuinfo` (`sse4_2` or `avx2` should be listed)

Comment: From your uname output, it looks like you're on an AWS instance.  The physical CPU should be a modern x86 (for energy-efficiency reasons).  But it's plausible their VM doesn't pass through AVX / AVX2 (or especially AVX-512) feature flags in CPUID for some types of instances.  So yeah, as @Smitop says, checking `/proc/cpuinfo` is the simplest way to check that.

Comment: AVX-512 gives a significant speedup for SIMDJSON over AVX2 (https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=simdjson-avx-512&num=1), so if you need or want to change instance type, you might want to pick on that has that enabled.  IDK if it benefits from any of the stuff new in Ice Lake that Cascade Lake doesn't have, but I wouldn't be surprised if `vpermb` byte shuffle is useful (AVX512VBMI).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [implementation of that function](https://github.com/simd-lite/simd-json/blob/f928ca4/src/lib.rs#L212-L221) is defined as follows:

```rust
#[cfg(all(
    not(feature = "allow-non-simd"),
    not(any(
        target_feature = "sse4.2",
        target_feature = "avx2",
        target_feature = "neon",
        target_feature = "simd128"
    ))
))]
fn please_compile_with_a_simd_compatible_cpu_setting_read_the_simdjsonrs_readme() -> ! {}
```

This means that the Rust compiler thinks your CPU doesn't have `sse4.2` or `avx2` or `neon` or `simd128`.

Your `/proc/cpuinfo` seems to have `avx2`, so is a giveaway of something strange going on.

The problem is that `rustflags` is not valid in your [`Cargo.toml`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html), it needs to be added to your [`.cargo/config.toml`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) file instead. The configuration file is meant primarily for global settings for cargo and rustc, but you can make one local to your repository in your project root. (e.g `myproject/.cargo/config.toml`)

If you look at the [example of `simd-json`](https://github.com/simd-lite/simd-json/blob/aa85faf/.cargo/config), you can see that is what they do.